# Receiving SSL wrong version number error when connecting to API

Tags: python, rest, ssl, insomnia, supabase

I'm attempting to connect to the Supabase API for my database. I've attempted to connect using [Python client for Supabase](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-py) and also using Insomnia. Both are giving me an SSL error of sorts.

I upgraded my openssl using Homebrew but seem to be still having the same error.

When I try and connect with the Insomnia client, here is the error I get:

`Error: SSL connect error`

and

```
 * Preparing request to https://***.supabase.co/rest/v1/asset
 * Current time is 2021-08-02T05:01:29.605Z
 * Using libcurl/7.73.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1k zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.9 libidn2/2.1.1 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.42.0
 * Using default HTTP version
 * Disable timeout
 * Enable automatic URL encoding
 * Enable SSL validation
 * Enable cookie sending with jar of 0 cookies
 * Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
 *   Trying 54.236.241.56:443...
 * Connected to qsnjdsplxqjlclaopkjc.supabase.co (54.236.241.56) port 443 (#10)
 * ALPN, offering h2
 * ALPN, offering http/1.1
 * successfully set certificate verify locations:
 *  CAfile: /var/folders/p_/9mjzfvts4ln1c9cvh32jpt_r0000gn/T/insomnia_2021.4.1/ca-certs.pem
 *  CApath: none
 * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
 * error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
 * Closing connection 10
```

When I try to connect using code, the error I receive is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='****.supabase.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/v1/asset (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mitchellwright/Desktop/scraper.py", line 23, in <module>
    data = supabase.table("asset").insert(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/supabase_py/lib/query_builder.py", line 31, in _execute_monkey_patch
    response = func(f"{url}?{query}", headers=self.session.headers, **additional_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='****.supabase.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/v1/asset (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to proceed here.

Comment: The server itself is fine. My guess is that there is some middlebox or software in between which is intercepting the connections, i.e. DPI firewall, captive portal, maybe a local antivirus or similar. There is likely nothing on the client side you can do to work around it apart from figuring out what is in between and trying to bypass it. For example it might be required to use an explicit proxy inside your network.

Comment: Ok I'll try it with a proxy. Very strange as I've never run into this error before, and haven't had this error with other APIs. Thanks for the help on where to start looking.